# Why can't Mathematica do this limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

(Glancing past the fact that one can do this by hand in a second...) Are there any extra conditions I can give Mathematica to make it evaluate limits like this? I'm not sure why it's getting choked up.
[image]

code:

```
k = Sqrt[(2 m \[CapitalEpsilon])/h^2];
\[Mu] = Sqrt[(2 m)/h^2 (\[CapitalEpsilon] + V)];
T = 1/(1 + (k^2 - \[Mu]^2)^2 Sin[2 \[Mu] a]^2/(4 k^2 \[Mu]^2));
Limit[T, \[CapitalEpsilon] -> \[Infinity]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your parameters are real, you can replace `Sin` by its range:

```
Limit[T /. Sin[_] :> Interval[{-1, 1}], Ε -> ∞]
(*  1  *)
```

Comment: +1 but `E` should be replaced by another symbol throughout.

Comment: @BobHanlon That's a `\[CapitalEpsilon]`, not an `E`.  Still, I would agree even that is a poor choice (potentially confusing).  `Limit` would complain if it were an `E`.

Comment: My oversight. Sorry.

Comment: @BobHanlon But that's exactly why it's a poor choice.  Still, it's the OP's code....

Comment: That's a neat trick! Thanks! Yeah, I know notation isn't the best :< I only used it cuz I try to stick to what is it in the problem I'm solving otherwise I get confused if I change too many variables.

Comment: @Solarmew Thanks & you're welcome.  Yeah, sometimes I get annoyed that `N` etc. are built-in symbols, esp, since `N` is such a common variable.  (I sometimes use `NN` in such cases, so I'm less likely to get confused.)